# Razor mediation function throwing invalid arguments error

Tags: razormediator

Not sure if I'm missing something obvious here, thought I'd post the question before I stop working on it hoping that someone can shed some light on the issue.

So I have the following in my razor template where `Fields.Doc` is a Component Link to a Component:

```
@using Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement;

@{
  var c = DoSomethingWithThisComponent(Fields.Doc);
}

@functions {
    public string DoSomethingWithThisComponent(Component component) {
        return component.BinaryContent.Filename;
    }
}
```

What I want to do is simply check the filename of a Binary if it exists, and then calculate it's filesize. I could have done this through a TBB but for the sake of a couple of lines of code I don't think this will be necessary.

So first of in my example above I  is to return the title of the Binary Component (I know I haven't checked for nulls I'm just trying to test it out) before I go on to extend this how I need. I'm seeing the following error though when running this in Template Builder:

> JScriptException: Expression 'RenderComponentPresentation()' had error 'The best overloaded method match for 'Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Razor.Templating.Rzr25ca82c514914f49b0d50e54bcfbf9f6Template.DoSomethingWithThisComponent(Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Component)' has some invalid arguments'

Am I missing something really obvious here? Using Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1.

### UPDATE

Thanks to Raj, I managed to use `Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Razor.Models` and ComponentModel to access `BinaryContent` like so:

```
    @functions {
      public string DoSomethingWithThisComponent(Component component) {
        return component.TridionObject.BinaryContent.Filename;
      }
    }
```

Comment: try following. DoSomethingWithThisComponent(Models.ComponentModel component component),

Comment: Ibrar whats your end goal? Can't this be better achieved by creating a C# TBB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Models.ComponentModel instead of Component. check sample below

```
@functions {
    public string DoSomethingWithThisComponent(Models.ComponentModel component) {
        return component.Title;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Raj. maybe I should have mentioned this but I need to access `BinaryContent`, can't seem to find any reference to this in ComponentModels, is this possible? I've updated my answer to add a bit more information.

Comment: Figured it out, I needed to use `TridionObject`. See update in my question.